# javascript this is undefined in a method

Tags: javascript

I want to add a value to an array, by parsing a method from a class to a function.

## Example

The Class:

```js
class Foo {
    constructor() {
        this.arr = [];
    }

    add(value) {
        this.arr.push(value);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```js
let foo = new Foo();
a(foo.add, "a String");

function a(func, value) {
    func(value);
}
```

Comment: Is this your actual code?  Because you're missing `this.` in your method.

Comment: `foo.add.bind(foo)`

Comment: @Daedalus no, this is not my actual code. i'm going to fix this

Comment: @Moritz In the future, remember to do that the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `add` function isn't bound to your object, which means that the `this` variable depends on the context it is in.

If you do

```
constructor() {
    this.arr = [];
    this.add = this.add.bind(this);
}
```

It will replace the add that is not bound to the new one that wherever you call it, it will reference this instance.

Or in ES6 you can do, which makes the same bind as my previous example but under the hood.

```
add = (value) => {
    this.arr.push(value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the constructor you need to bind the add function to that class.

`this.add = this.add.bind(this);`

Also you need to refer to arr variable with this.
`this.arr.push`

Which keeps the context of that instance of Foo.

Answer (score 0):

Use arrow function to prevent auto bind `add = (value) => {...}`